# CSS Animation - Moving to start position

Tags: css, css-animations

I have a CSS animation that move an object from left to right, and back again using:

```
@-moz-keyframes animation_1{
    0%  { -moz-transform:  translateX(100px); }
    25% { -moz-transform:  translateX(200px);}
    50% { -moz-transform:  translateX(0px); }
    75% { -moz-transform:  translateX(300px); }
    100%{ -moz-transform:  translateX(100px);}
}
```

This animation runs on an infinite loop.

At a certain point I want the object to move to position X, say 50px, and stop.

I've tried adding a second animation class (via javascript), that would move the object in to it's final position using:

```
@-moz-keyframes droid-catching-position
{
     0% {   }
   100% { -moz-transform:  translateX(20px); }  
}
```

But this causes the object to jump in to the second animation, rather than transition.

Does anyone have any suggestions or hint on how to almost tween between 2 animations?

Comment: What do you mean, stop? You can specify that your animation be used only once in your `-webkit-animation` property.

Comment: Well the animation runs indefinitely until the user interacts with something. Then a new class is applied, with a new animation that moves the object from it's current location (which could be at any point during the initial animation) to it's final destination.

Comment: The second animation only runs once, the problem is the jump between animation a and animation b.

Comment: Why don't you use jQuery to remove the first class and add the new class?

Comment: Trying to avoid javascript would be a reason for making animations with CSS only. But when you try to inflict in the animation with javascript anyways, then why not make the whole thing i jQuery?

Comment: Javascript / jQuery is an option, but the second animation could also be trigger by a hover, which would avoid the need for javascript all together. While jQuery maybe the answer for a lot of things, you shouldn't reply on it for everything.